# Facebook like box error on firefox in xd_arbiter.php

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-likebox

I'm trying to use the LikeBox in this site http://grandprix.webtraffic.com.br, it works perfectly on Chrome but on FireFox it keeps getting this error on the facebook file .../xd_arbiter.php?version=25:

> JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal  Line 13

here are the codes:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
// init the FB JS SDK
FB.init({
    appId      : 'myBigAppIdIsHere',
    channelUrl : 'http://grandprix.webtraffic.com.br/channel.html',
    status     : true,
    xfbml      : true
});            
};
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And for the like box:

```
<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/LinhaGrandPrix" width="390" height="430" show_faces="false" colorscheme="dark" stream="true" show_border="false" header="false"></fb:like-box>
```

anyone have come across this issue or know whats is happening?